# iOS 13 Shortcuts: Problem with Maps action Search Local Businesses

Tags: ios, sirishortcuts, ipados

Since iOS 13, every time I use shortcuts that include the Maps action "Search Local Businesses" (homemade or from the Shortcuts Gallery, e.g. "Find Gas Nearby" or "Walk to Coffee Shop") I get the error message

> Invalid argument. You must provide a radius value to Search Local
>   Businesses

When I look into the shortcuts I can confirm that the radius is (pre-)set to 1.5km, so the value is there.

The problem persists on iPhone with iOS 13 through 13.1.2 and iPad with iPadOS 13 through 13.1.2. The exact same shortcuts worked just fine on iPhone and iPad running iOS 12.

Any ideas what's wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that location services aren't enabled. Go to Settings > Privacy > Location Services. Ensure Location Services is on and Maps and Shortcuts show up in the list as While Using.

Comment: Location services are enabled. Both Maps and Shortcuts show up as While Using. I also tried to remove and re-add the shortcuts, and I tried to delete the app, restart the device, and re-install the app. Same error every time.